# Странное поведение медиа запросов

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Столкнулся со странным поведением медиа запросов. Верстаю страницу desctop-first и пишу медиа от max-width, от большего к меньшему. Однако почему-то один медиа запрос перебивает другой, хотя он находится выше по строчкам кода. Что примечательно другой медиа запрос, с шириной больше, работает как надо.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Прикладываю скрин, там всё видно.

Comment: Да, есть. Вот такой <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: У меня так же и написано, только если добавить initial-scale=", то вся вёрстка летит.

Comment: Нет, я подозреваю, что это сборщик где-то ошибается и по cssmap всё нормально, а на деле этот меди запрос ниже.
Пойду посмотрю на собранном проекте.